# fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock! when using a WaitGroup with a for-select loop

Tags: go, channel

**go version:** go1.12.5 linux/amd64

I was trying to understand nil channels in Go.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    ch2 := make(chan int)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(c1 chan int, c2 chan int, w *sync.WaitGroup) {
        for c1 != nil || c2 != nil {
            fmt.Println("in for")
            fmt.Println(c1, c2)
            select {
            case v, ok := <-c1:
                if !ok {
                    c1 = nil
                    fmt.Println("c1 closed")
                } else {
                    fmt.Println(v, " recieved c1")
                }
            case v, ok := <-c2:
                if !ok {
                    c2 = nil
                } else {
                    fmt.Println(v, " recieved c2")
                }
            }
        }
        fmt.Println("called wg.Done")
        wg.Done()
    }(ch, ch2, &wg)
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        if i%2 == 0 {
            ch <- i
        } else {
            ch2 <- i
        }
    }
    close(ch)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

And received this output on the stdout:

```
in for
0xc000084060 0xc0000840c0
0  recieved c1
in for
0xc000084060 0xc0000840c0
1  recieved c2
in for
0xc000084060 0xc0000840c0
2  recieved c1
in for
0xc000084060 0xc0000840c0
3  recieved c2
in for
0xc000084060 0xc0000840c0
c1 closed
in for
<nil> 0xc0000840c0
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xc00009a018)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sema.go:56 +0x39
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0xc00009a010)
        /usr/local/go/src/sync/waitgroup.go:130 +0x65
main.main()
        /home/ayush/projects/gojects/src/go-practice/nil-channels/main.go:44 +0x155

goroutine 18 [select]:
main.main.func1(0xc00009a010, 0xc000084060, 0xc0000840c0, 0xc00009a010)
        /home/ayush/projects/gojects/src/go-practice/nil-channels/main.go:17 +0x1e5
created by main.main
        /home/ayush/projects/gojects/src/go-practice/nil-channels/main.go:13 +0xce
exit status 2
```

But according to the code and the logs, `wg.Done()` is never called, that means that the goroutine is still alive.

Could anyone help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: deadlock means the goroutines are "alive", so yes, it's no surprise that they are alive. The problem is that all goroutines are waiting for each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only close `ch`, not `ch2`. When `ch` is closed, the goroutine sets `c1` to nil, but `c2` is still not nil, so `select` waits to receive from `c2`, and the main goroutine waits at `wg.Done()`, so both goroutines are asleep.

Comment: Ah, I see. Also, I realised that adding a `default` case seems to make it not crash but blocks indefinitely, and from your explanation it seems that it is because the goroutine does not have to wait on `ch2`, is that right?

Comment: If you add a `default` case, `select` will not block, and the for loop will keep spinning until you close the second channel.

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because you're not closing `ch2`. The select block is still waiting for `ch2`.

Working code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    ch2 := make(chan int)
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)

    go func(c1 chan int, c2 chan int, w *sync.WaitGroup) {
        for c1 != nil || c2 != nil {

            select {
            case v, ok := <-c1:
                if !ok {
                    c1 = nil
                    fmt.Println("c1 closed")
                } else {
                    fmt.Println(v, " recieved c1")
                }
            case v, ok := <-c2:
                if !ok {
                    c2 = nil
                } else {
                    fmt.Println(v, " recieved c2")
                }
            }
        }

        fmt.Println("called wg.Done")
        wg.Done()
    }(ch, ch2, &wg)

    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        if i%2 == 0 {
            ch <- i
            fmt.Println("sending to c1 ", i)
        } else {
            ch2 <- i
            fmt.Println("sending to c2 ", i)
        }
    }
    close(ch)
    close(ch2)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: That was the intent though, I was expecting it to block indefinitely

Comment: If your intent was to block indefinitely, then it would cause a deadlock.